# how to get AppleScript and jQuery to fire a '.click()' event in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, applescript

I am trying to get some javascript code, with jQuery loaded in an AppleScript, to fire a '.click()' event.

Here's a look at the code in question:

```
var dayIdValue1 = 'z_event_date_picker_calendar_0_cell' + dayValue2;

var dayTd = document.getElementById(dayIdValue1).childNodes[0];
dayTd.click();
```

It's probably worth mentioning that I tried to get jQuery to load a selector with the variable dayIdValue1, but I couldn't get it to work without an error.

Also it's worth adding, that I am using Safari to run the script, but it keeps firing an error like this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'dayTd.click()')
```

Any help you would have to offer on the matter would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value and type of `dayIdValue1` and `dayId` ?

Comment: dayIdValue1 is the id of a table cell (TD) that contains a link (A) that needs to be clicked in order to trigger a script on the page that this AppleScript has loaded. dayIdValue's type is a string and dayTd's type is an element object of type 'A'.

Comment: .childNodes[0] references an 'A' link.

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment that it is a link, you can use `getElementsByTagName` to reference the anchor tag.

```
var dayIdValue1 = 'z_event_date_picker_calendar_0_cell' + dayValue2;
var dayTd = document.getElementById(dayIdValue1).getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
dayTd.click();
```

With jQuery it would just be

```
jQuery("#" + dayIdValue1 + " a").click();
```

this assumes that `dayIdValue1` is a valid id.

Comment: i will give this a try. one sec.

Comment: it didn't quite work. it threw back this error message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'dayTd.click()')

Comment: i've got good news and bad news. the jQuery selector syntax caused the page to not throw back an error. However, it didn't trigger the form code on the page. hmmmm....

Comment: i'm trying to get the code to update a form on this site called zvents.com (http://www.zvents.com/). They have a form under their 'Add an Event' section that uses some YUI or jQuery code to populate a form with data from a visual calendar. I tried to get this code to trigger the form using regular javascript, but i found out the link node doesn't work using the 'click' method.

Comment: i don't think the jQuery selector syntax worked because I tried to use the jQuery selector syntax to activate a '.focus()' event and nothing happened, but when I tried 'dayTd.focus()' the page responded accordingly.